# How can i reverse sort a letter by occurrence but if it has the amount of occurrences sort it alphabetically?

Tags: unix

So I am making exercises for practice but i encountered something confusing. I need to count the amount of times every letter in a text document occurred and then print them one after another, the letter that appears the most first.

The problem lies in the fact that i need to sort the letters with the same number of occurrence alphabetically. It's a problem because sort automatically sort alphabetically so when I reverse sort by occurrence it automatically sorts the letters with the same number of occurrence in reverse alphabetical order.

I've tried to sort per column so it sorts the numbers first and the letters after but that doesn't work.

So lets just work with a few letters now.

```
echo eeeeerrrbbbcccnN | tr a-z A-Z | grep -iE [a-z] -o | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | tr -d 0-9'\n '
```

The output is ERCBN but it needs to be EBCRN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify multiple sort conditions:

```
$ # OP's attempt
$ echo eeeeerrrbbbcccnN | tr a-z A-Z | grep -iE [a-z] -o | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
      5 E
      3 R
      3 C
      3 B
      2 N

$ # multiple column sort
$ # also note the change in grep command
$ echo eeeeerrrbbbcccnN | tr a-z A-Z | grep -o [A-Z] | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2,2
      5 E
      3 B
      3 C
      3 R
      2 N
```

Comment: If the `grep [A-Z]` does not matter, the `grep` can be just shortened to `grep -o '.'`

Comment: yeah good point, but OP's actual data might have characters other than letters too..